# Jetty 6 and Java 7

Tags: java, jetty

I have an old Jetty 6.1.26 which works with Java 1.5. I can't change my Jetty version,but I'm interested by changing my Java version. My Jetty version, is it compatible with Java 1.7?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: +1 to the answer below but also you should really look into updating your jetty install, we are releasing milestones of 9.1 at this point and there have been a lot of improvements since then

Answer (score 3):

Java SE 6 is practically binary compatible with Java SE 5.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html

And Java SE 7 the same to Java SE 6
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html

Unless you're unlucky and run into one of the known incompatibilities, I'd say it will work. But why don't you just try?

Comment: small caveat that Jetty 6.1.26 was released when there were a number of nio bugs in the jdk so it includes work arounds for many of those common nio bugs of the time.  those issues have since been resolved and we do not test back against that version on modern java versions to ensure that the workarounds don't break their fixes....that whole nio instability period was one of the impetuses to rework the IO layer for jetty 9 (in addition to modern protocol support like spdy and websocket, etc)